# Adding new column to merged DataFrame based on pre-merged DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two DataFrames, df1 and df2. In my code I used Pandas.concat method to find the differences between them.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(latest_file, 0)
df2 = pd.read_excel(latest_file, 1)
#Reads first and second sheet inside spreadsheet.

new_dataframe = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

This works perfectly, however I want to know which rows are coming from df1, and which are coming from df2. to show this I want to add a column to new_dataframe, if it's from df1 to say "Removed" in the new column, and to say 'Added' if it's from df2. I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: In my current code it removed all columns which are identical in each DataFrame. The solution has to still remove the common rows.

Comment: Easiest way is just to add those columns to the original `df1` and `df2` before concatenating them.

Comment: @MichaelCao I tried that, but then the two dfs had differences, causing it to not remove the rows which are a part of both dataframes while using pd.concat. Is there a way ignore them while concatenating if I add them beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `pd.merge` with `indicator=True` instead. This will create a new column named `_merge` that indicates which value came from which column. You can modify this to say `Removed` and `Added`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [3,4,5,6,7]})

m = {'left_only': 'Removed', 'right_only': 'Added'}

new_dataframe = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator=True) \
                  .query('_merge != "both"') \ 
                  .replace({'_merge': m})
```

Output:

```
   col1   _merge
0     1  Removed
1     2  Removed
5     6    Added
6     7    Added
```

Comment: This for the most part works, but an important part of this is that the rows which are in both columns get removed completely. (I will add that note to my original post), so is there a way to keep this and still have the .drop_duplicates(keep=False) [Remove the boths]? I tried to add it between the .merge and .replace, but it did not remove them.

Comment: Take a look at the updated solution that removes rows within both columns.